# Mysql - Determinate number of inserted rows in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

So, basically I have this sql stored procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists registrar_cuenta; 
delimiter // 

create procedure registrar_cuenta (in p_email varchar(255), in p_passwordHash varchar(40), in p_salt varchar(40)) 
    begin 
        if (exists(select 1 from usuarios where email = p_email and registrado = 0)) then 
            update usuarios set passwordHash = p_passwordHash, salt = p_salt, fechaRegistro = now(), registrado = 1  where email = p_email and registrado = 0; 
        else
            insert into usuarios (email, passwordHash, salt, fechaRegistro, registrado) values (p_email, p_passwordHash, p_salt, now(), 1); 
        end if; 
    end 
    // 

delimiter ;
```

Which runs great, BUT I want to change this piece of code:

```
else
    insert into usuarios (email, passwordHash, salt, fechaRegistro, registrado) values (p_email, p_passwordHash, p_salt, now(), 1); 
end if;
```

For something like this:

```
    insert into usuarios (email, passwordHash, salt, fechaRegistro, registrado) values (p_email, p_passwordHash, p_salt, now(), 1); 

    if (inserted_rows == 0) then 
        alter table usuarios auto_increment = auto_increment - 1; 
    end if;
```

The thing is that I have an unique field (email) which can produce a duplicate entry error, if so, then the auto_increment value will increase anyways and I want to avoid that.

Is there any way I could archieve this task?

Comment: Did you try to calculate `count after - count before` insert?

Comment: Hi, thank's for comment, It's my last alternative since I want to know if exists any optimized form (afected boolean, etc) to determinate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the `ROW_COUNT` function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for, but it seems that mysql wont let to reset the auto_increment in order to protect the data (it throws a syntax error). The clause is the one I just mentionated before: "alter table usuarios auto_increment = auto_increment - 1"

Comment: Both answers are great, the @Rawinder's answer actually made me to take a decision, but this answer definetely resolves the problem of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

***MySQL Solution***:

You can use `alter table ...` as in the example below:

```
alter table usuarios
 auto_increment = ( SELECT ( AUTO_INCREMENT - 1 )
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME='usuarios' and TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
                  );
```

But, this practice is discouraged. If you define a column with `int unsigned` max value you can store is `4294967295` and if it is `bigint unsigned` max value is `18446744073709551615`. If the database engine can insert `100,000` records per second, calculate your self, how many *hours ( days / months / years )* would it take to cross the max value. Hence, you can omit the auto incremented value that is wasted.

Comment: Thank's for clarify this point, yeah I just readed something like that somewhere else, and yes it causes an unnecesary overhead, I I will leave it like that